# Predictability and progressively measurability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

It is well known that predictable processes (i.e. stochastic processes measurable wrt the sigma field generated by simple processes) are progressively measurable processes.

If the underlying sigma algebra is the augmented natural filtration generated by a brownian motion then for every progressively measurable process there exists a modification which is predictable. Is that in general true also if the filtration is just a complete and right continuous (but not generated by the BM)?